# calculating contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

It would like to find an expression for

$ \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i}\int \limits_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} n^s (s-1)^{-e^{iu}}/s^2 ds$
 where $0<|u| \leq \pi/6$, so $\Re(e^{iu}) \geq 1/2$ and $\log(s-1) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $s>1$ and $c>1$, I
 have already proved (using Hankel contour)

$ \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i}\int \limits_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} n^s (s-1)^{-e^{iu}}= n \log(n)^{1-e^{iu}}/\Gamma(e^{iu})ds$
where $\Gamma$ is the usual gamma Function. Some ideas? I'm not sure there is an expression for it.

Comment: What is the result of $$n\frac{d}{dn}\left(n\frac{d}{dn}\right)\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{n^s(s-1)^{e^{iu}}}{s^2}\,ds$$

Comment: Because having uniform convergence I would calculate

Comment: using @Dr. MV hint I calculate 

$n \dfrac{d}{dn}(n \dfrac{d}{dn} )\int \limits_{c- i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \dfrac{n^s(s-1)^{-e^{iu}}}{s^2}
= n \dfrac{d}{dn}\int \limits_{c- i \infty}^{c+i \infty} n \dfrac{n^{s-1}(s-1)^{-e^{iu}}}{s} =  \int \limits_{c- i \infty}^{c+i \infty}  {n^{s}(s-1)^{-e^{iu}}}= n \log(n)^{1-e^{iu}}/\Gamma(e^{iu})
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There was a typographical error in the OP.  Therefore, we will begin by developing the solution for the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} n^{z}(z-1)^{-a}\,dz$.  To that end, we proceed.

---

**PART $1$:**

First, let $g(n)$ be the function with integral representation

$$g(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} n^{z}(z-1)^{-a}\,dz \tag 1$$

where $n\in \mathbb{R}$, $n>0$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$, $c>1$, $a\in \mathbb{C}$, $|a|=1$ and $0<\arg(a)\le \pi/6$.

We choose the branch cut that extends from $z=1$ to $z=-\infty$ along the real axis.  Then, we can deform the contour and write the integral in $(1)$ as

$$\begin{align}
g(n)&=\frac{n}{2\pi i} \left( \int_{0}^{-\infty} n^x e^{-a(\log(|x|)+i\pi)}\,dx-\int_{0}^{-\infty}n^x e^{-a(\log(|x|)-i\pi)}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\frac{n\sin(a\pi)}{\pi}\int_0^\infty n^{-x}x^{-a}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{n\sin(a\pi)}{\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-x\log(n)}x^{-a}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{n\sin(a\pi)}{\pi}\log^{a-1}(n)\int_0^\infty x^{-a}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{n\sin(a\pi)}{\pi}\log^{a-1}(n)\Gamma(1-a)\\\\
&=\frac{n\log^{a-1}(n)}{\Gamma(a)}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} n^{z}(z-1)^{-a}\,dz=\frac{n\log^{a-1}(n)}{\Gamma(a)}}$$

---

**PART $2$:**

Next, let $f(n)$ be the function with integral representation

$$f(n)=\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{n^z(z-1)^{-a}}{z^2}\,dz $$

Then, note that

$$\begin{align}
n\frac{d}{dn}\left(n\frac{d}{dn}\right)f(n)&=n\frac{d}{dn}\left(n\frac{d}{dn}\right)\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{n^z(z-1)^{-a}}{z^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}n^z(z-1)^{-a}\,dz\\\\
&=g(n)\\\\
&=\frac{n\log^{a-1}(n)}{\Gamma(a)}
\end{align}$$

Now, solving the ODE

$$n\frac{d}{dn}\left(n\frac{d}{dn}\right)f(n)=\frac{n\log(n)^{a-1}}{\Gamma(a)}$$

we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{n^z(z-1)^{-a}}{z^2}\,dz=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^n \log^{a-1}(n')\log(n/n')\,dn'} \tag 2$$

---

**NOTE:**

> We could enforce the substitution $n'=e^{-t}$ in $(2)$ and use the definition of the [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) to express the integral of interest in terms of the Incomplete Gamma Function.  We will leave that exercise to the interested reader.

Comment: thank you for the hint,  I confused by the condition $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ why one can do this assumption?

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.  In order to solve the second order ODE, we need conditions on the unknown $f$ in order to find the integration constants.  -Mark

Comment: @ Dr. MV you are sure there is a solution in easy terms? I have tried it to solve but it doesn't work :(

Comment: The term should be $\log(n)^{1-e^{iu}}=(\log(n))^{1-e^{iu}}$

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.  -Mark